# Partial eta square values summing to greater than 1

Tags: r, anova, effect-size, sums-of-squares, partial-effect

I am trying to run a factorial ANOVA analysis with partial effects, but it seems that my partial eta square values are totalling above 1, particularly when I specify my contrast with Type II or Type III (orthogonal contrast) Sums of squares.

What is the correct procedure for running and interpreting these effects?

The partial eta squares total to below 1, but only when using default contrasts with Type III sum of squares. However, using Type III sums of squares with default treatment contrasts [does not seem to be the recommended approach](https://blog.msbstats.info/posts/2021-05-25-everything-about-anova/#centering).

My understanding is that partial eta squares should not sum to above 1, but one comment by @MarjoleinFokkema briefly mentions that ["partial R2s need not sum to 1"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/587353/what-is-the-difference-between-partial-eta-squared-and-partial-r-squared-in-fact#comment1085902_587355), which might have bearing on this topic.

Reprex:

```r
library(palmerpenguins) # dataset
library(car) # anova functions
library(effectsize) # effect sizes
library(dplyr)
library(emmeans)

# assigns data to a dataframe we call "df"
df <- palmerpenguins::penguins

# drop rows with missing values
df <- df[complete.cases(df)==TRUE, ]

df$id <- seq(1, nrow(df))

# basic fit
flipper_fit <- lm(flipper_length_mm ~ species*sex, data = df)

effectsize::eta_squared(flipper_fit, partial = TRUE, alternative="two.sided")
#> # Effect Size for ANOVA (Type I)
#> 
#> Parameter   | Eta2 (partial) |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------------------
#> species     |           0.83 | [0.80, 0.85]
#> sex         |           0.27 | [0.20, 0.35]
#> species:sex |           0.03 | [0.00, 0.07]

# Type 2 anova
m_anova<- car::Anova(flipper_fit, type = 2)

effectsize::eta_squared(m_anova, partial = TRUE, alternative="two.sided")
#> # Effect Size for ANOVA (Type II)
#> 
#> Parameter   | Eta2 (partial) |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------------------
#> species     |           0.83 | [0.80, 0.85]
#> sex         |           0.27 | [0.20, 0.35]
#> species:sex |           0.03 | [0.00, 0.07]


# Type 3 with default contrasts
m_anova3 <- car::Anova(flipper_fit, type = 3)

effectsize::eta_squared(m_anova3, partial = TRUE, alternative="two.sided")
#> Type 3 ANOVAs only give sensible and informative results when covariates
#>   are mean-centered and factors are coded with orthogonal contrasts (such
#>   as those produced by `contr.sum`, `contr.poly`, or `contr.helmert`, but
#>   *not* by the default `contr.treatment`).
#> # Effect Size for ANOVA (Type III)
#> 
#> Parameter   | Eta2 (partial) |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------------------
#> species     |           0.67 | [0.62, 0.71]
#> sex         |           0.07 | [0.03, 0.13]
#> species:sex |           0.03 | [0.00, 0.07]


# Setting contrasts
contrasts(df$species) <- contr.sum

contrasts(df$sex) <- contr.sum

# Type 3 anova with orthogonal contrasts
flipper_fit_orth <- lm(flipper_length_mm ~ species*sex, data = df)

m_anova3_orth <- car::Anova(flipper_fit_orth, type = 3)

effectsize::eta_squared(m_anova3_orth, partial = TRUE, alternative="two.sided")
#> Type 3 ANOVAs only give sensible and informative results when covariates
#>   are mean-centered and factors are coded with orthogonal contrasts (such
#>   as those produced by `contr.sum`, `contr.poly`, or `contr.helmert`, but
#>   *not* by the default `contr.treatment`).
#> # Effect Size for ANOVA (Type III)
#> 
#> Parameter   | Eta2 (partial) |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------------------
#> species     |           0.83 | [0.80, 0.85]
#> sex         |           0.27 | [0.20, 0.35]
#> species:sex |           0.03 | [0.00, 0.07]



# afex method
afex_anova <- afex::aov_ez(id='id',
                           dv='flipper_length_mm',
                           data=df,
                           between = c('species','sex'),
                           anova_table = list(es = "pes")
)  
#> Contrasts set to contr.sum for the following variables: species, sex

afex_anova
#> Anova Table (Type 3 tests)
#> 
#> Response: flipper_length_mm
#>        Effect     df   MSE          F  pes p.value
#> 1     species 2, 327 31.98 782.88 *** .827   <.001
#> 2         sex 1, 327 31.98 122.02 *** .272   <.001
#> 3 species:sex 2, 327 31.98    5.14 ** .031    .006
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '+' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>